# AngularJS and _target=self with routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-routing

A slightly odd question I know but I'm trying to figure out mixing angular routing with a standard page.

I have a menu system that has 4 items, only one has a target of _self, the routing is working correctly.

The page in question is my overall site layout page, what I'm trying to achieve is once I switch back with the menu to a page that is managed by angular routing all the content in the div with and id of "full-page-content" be removed.

```
 <div id="full-page-content">@RenderBody()</div>
 <ng-view></ng-view>
```

In the long run I'll let angular manage everything but I'm thinking about this from a migration perspective.

Thanks

Comment: Not 100% clear on what you want to do? Is it just clear `#full-page-content` when you're in an angular page? Or do you need to handle putting it back if you go back to the _self page?

Comment: Just want to remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a directive to do this that checks the current route, then clears if it changes to something other than the one not driven by angular.

Something like this:

```
app.directive("clearWhenNot", function($location){

  return {

    scope: { selfRoute: "@clearWhenNot" },    

    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
      // watch location.path
      scope.$watch( 
        function (){ return $location.path(); }, 

        function(newVal, oldVal){
          // blank the html if the route isn't the _self one.
          if(newVal != scope.selfRoute){
            element.html('');
          }
        }
      );
    } 
  }

});
```

I haven't tested this, so let me know if it works - there may be typos!

**EDIT** to use it:

```
<div id="full-page-content" clear-when-not="somenonangularroute">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Which would clear the page if you weren't at `www.yourapp.com/somenonangularroute`.